# How can I remove the duplicate edge between two tile objects

Tags: mesh, seams

Here is what my object looks like, it is a combination of four tile objects.

[image]

The seams are very visible. How can I remove them after join those objects?

Comment: You can use Merge by Distance or other merge tool. There are merge options in some modifiers like Mirror or Array. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html#merging

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but how can I select all those vertices at the dividing line once time?

Comment: You can select all the verts, not necessary only the edge. But there is a function for this Select>>Select Loops>>Select Boundary Loop (Select everything first).

Comment: Thanks, that really works for me.